# Pure typescript package import with paths

Tags: typescript

I have a pure typescript local package. Importing like this goes fine

```
import { NavigationItem } from 'nx-ui'
```

I'd like to import like this, which doesn't work (module not found)

```
import { NavigationItem } from 'nx-ui/components/nav'
```

I have the following structure:

```
root/index.ts
> root/components
>> root/components/nav
>>> root/components/nav/index.ts
```

How do I fix my type definition?

This is my `global.d.ts`:

```
declare module 'nx-ui/components/column' {
  const value
  export default value
}

declare module 'nx-ui/components/nav' {}
declare module 'nx-ui/components/misc' {}
declare module 'nx-ui/components/row' {}

declare module 'nx-ui' {
  export * from 'nx-ui/components/column'
  export * from 'nx-ui/components/nav'
  export * from 'nx-ui/components/row'
  export * from 'nx-ui/components/misc'
}
```

Comment: Would it import if it was `nx-ui/components/nav/index.ts`?

Comment: ending with .ts isn't possible (error)and `nx-ui/components/nav/index` cant be found as well.